# Maths-Physics question, can I solve this situation for $x$?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

So Let's say I have an object going at velocity $V$, initially. Each second, the current velocity $v$ is reduced by $v/x$ . After $250$ (arbitrary) seconds the velocity has been reduced to below/equal $0.01$ (arbitrary small amount). What is $x$?

The only formula I can really come up with describes only a single time-interval-step.

*v<sub>new</sub> = v<sub>old</sub> - (v<sub>old</sub>/x)*

But I would like to have a formula where I can plug in:
-Initial velocity, *V<sub>initial</sub>*
-Number of time-steps, *n*
-Final velocity, *V<sub>final</sub>*

...and get $x$.

(I hope this isn't too Physics-y for y'all. I'm not even sure if this can be done, but I thought that coming up with abstract formulas like this is more a mathematically-inclined thing so that's why I'm posting here.)

Comment: Need some clarification here.  Are you looking for a calculus-based solution?  And this is a one-dimensional problem, with $x$ being position and $v$ being velocity?  So essentially your rate of change of velocity (acceleration) depends on position?

Comment: No sorry, x is just 'unknown factor', not position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that each step down in speed happens exactly each second which is strange.

$$V_{n+1} = V_{n}(1-\frac{1}{x})$$

Therefore:

$$V_{n+k} = V_{n}(1-\frac{1}{x})^k$$

and

$$V_{f} = V_{i}(1-\frac{1}{x})^n$$

Comment: And hence to complete the problem, $$1-\frac{1}{x} = \sqrt[n]{\frac{V_f}{V_i}} \implies x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{V_f}{V_i}}-1}.$$

Comment: That's it! Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity though, what exactly is happening with the introduction and reduction of k in lines 2 and 3?

Comment: Never mind I see it now. That was actually a crucial part of my problem- I didn't notice that for each time increment it was just multiplying the RHS by (1 - 1/x). Thanks again.